# Paying off the interest of a student loan with interest earned from investments

Tags: riba, loan

Assalaamu alaikum.  I have student loans that are accruing a lot of interest.  I have an investment account given to me by my employer, but I have not made any personal contributions to it because some of the investments in that account earn interest.  However, if I start putting my own money into that investment account, and allow it to build up (through a combination of dividends, ROI, and interest), could I use that money (which would include interest) to pay down my student loans (and the interest) faster?